# Sencha Touch App Displays Right in Safari but not in Chrome Any Longer

Tags: google-chrome, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have a Sencha Touch App developed in Architect which worked perfectly as of November 2013. Since been busy with other things but recently fired up Sencha Architect again and accepted to update with the newest build of Architect 3. After re-building my app, I noticed some things:

1) whilst it worked perfectly on desktop Chrome back then, some screens now do not display correctly. On the specific screen I have this issue, no error or warning is displayed. However there are some warnings from the prior (card layout)

2) when I build for Android (the intended platform for the app), everything displays right but some events do not respond when deployed to a phone (specifically onChange of a field); as I don't get this far on Chrome where I can read the console log (due to problem 1, I cannot even analyse problem 2)

3) as a webapp, all displays right on Mobile Safari and Mobile Chrome but in both cases, the onChange problem (problem 2) remains

4) everything displayed and still displays correctly as a webapp on Desktop Safari. The onChange event works on Safari but the tap-hold (which works by holding down the left mouse button on Chrome) does not work

The main problem I would like to solve is the desktop Chrome display problem as depicted in the following screen shots. I also provide the code of that screen + the few warnings that get displayed in chrome console log prior to navigating to the screen.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code:

```
{
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Invoice',
            iconCls: 'info',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    flex: 3,
                    docked: 'top',
                    height: '80%',
                    itemId: 'Invoice',
                    scrollable: 'vertical',
                    itemTpl: [
                        '<div>{ProductName}</br> ==> {Cases}c/ {Rolls}r/ {Units}u  @ {LineTotText}</div>'
                    ],
                    store: 'SKUStore',
                    infinite: true,
                    striped: true,
                    variableHeights: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    height: '20%',
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            flex: 1,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    itemId: 'invoicetotal',
                                    label: 'Total',
                                    readOnly: true
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            flex: 1,
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'container',
                                    flex: 1,
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'button',
                                            itemId: 'CancelInvoice',
                                            ui: 'decline',
                                            text: 'Cancel'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'container',
                                    flex: 1,
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'button',
                                            ui: 'action',
                                            text: 'Finalize'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627787/sencha-touch-2-2-application-layout-breaks-in-chrome-29

Comment: Thanks but thats already what's in the file specified in that location.

Comment: @user1729972 Did you ever figure out the problem?